# When using FileStream.ReadAsync() should I open the file in async mode?

Tags: c#, async-await, filestream, beginread

The old .Net way of performing asynchronous I/O for a `FileStream` is to use [`FileStream.BeginRead()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt5ahzw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`FileStream.EndRead()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/525xt96h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The MSDN documentation for `FileStream.BeginRead()` states:

> FileStream provides two different modes of operation: synchronous I/O and asynchronous I/O. While either can be used, the underlying operating system resources might allow access in only one of these modes.
>
> By default, FileStream opens the operating system handle synchronously. In Windows, this slows down asynchronous methods. **If asynchronous methods are used, use the FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare, Int32, Boolean) constructor.**

The `.Net 4.5x` way of performing asynchronous I/O for a `FileStream` is to use [`Stream.ReadAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The MSDN documentation for `FileStream.ReadAsync()` links directly to the documentation for `Stream.ReadAsync()`. This documentation does not mention any need to open the file in async mode; indeed, the sample code in the documentation manifestly does not do so.

I therefore assume that when using `File.ReadAsync()` there is no need to open the file in async mode.

Is this assumption correct?

[EDIT]

I have just discovered [an MSDN article on using Async for File Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/jj155757.aspx).

This states:

> The examples in this topic use the FileStream class, which has an option that causes asynchronous I/O to occur at the operating system level. By using this option, you can avoid blocking a ThreadPool thread in many cases.
>
> **To enable this option, you specify the useAsync=true or options=FileOptions.Asynchronous argument in the constructor call.**

So now I'm thinking that I *should* be opening the file in asynchronous mode... If so, it's somewhat unfortunate that the sample code provided in the documentation for `ReadAsync()` does *not* open the file asynchronously!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In win32, you need to specify [FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make use of asynchronous File IO. In .net world you use `isAsync` parameter of `FileStream` to achieve the same. If you fail to do so, operations will not be asynchronous.

It is a shame that `FileStream.ReadAsync` and its related methods failed to document it.

You can confirm this by peeking into the implementation.

```
public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   ...
    if (!this._isAsync || !Environment.IsWindowsVistaOrAbove)
    {
        return base.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);
    }
    ...
    return stateObject;
}
```

`base.ReadAsync` will eventually call to `Stream.Read` method synchronously in `ThreadPool` giving the impression that operation is async, but really not.

Related information from [Concurrent Programming On Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) book (Pg:818):

> As with `CreateFile`, you must specify at creation time that you'd
>   like to use a FileStream for asynchronous execution. With
>   `FileStream`, you do this by passing true as the `isAsync` argument to
>   the constructor overloads, which accept it. The stream's `IsAsync`
>   property will subsequently return true. If you fail to pass this
>   value, calls to `BeginRead` and `BeginWrite` will succeed. But they
>   will use the base class implementation from Stream, which provides
>   none of the benefits of true asynchronous file I/O.

Above information is about APM methods(as this is old book) but still relevant one.

Comment: This is very important to know! There seem to be many web pages which discuss `ReadAsync()` but fail to mention this very important fact (for example, http://www.dotnetperls.com/async)

Comment: Yes, the website you linked is a pretty good one but sadly that failed to talk about this. I see that link says with async we're using only single thread and shows example with stream reader. That's wrong because implementation happens to use `ThreadPool` without the `isAsync` flag :(