# Why to assign null before initialize object in C#

Tags: c#

I'm following a tutorial on how to use capture video using the [Windows MediaCapture API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642092.aspx) on Windows Phone and on the code examples, some of the variables are set to null just before assigning a new instance.

```
private void InitCaptureSettings() {
    _captureInitSettings = null;
    _captureInitSettings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
    _captureInitSettings.AudioDeviceId = "";
    _captureInitSettings.VideoDeviceId = "";
    _captureInitSettings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.AudioAndVideo;
    _captureInitSettings.PhotoCaptureSource = Windows.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;

    if (_deviceList.Count > 0) {
        _captureInitSettings.VideoDeviceId = _deviceList[0].Id;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why this should be done?

Thanks

Comment: In that method? No, it's pointless. However, when not following an example, member variables are typically set during object initialization to a programmer-defined "default" value as some defaults won't fit with how they are to be used.

Comment: It changes the behavior. If `MediaCaptureInitializationSettings` constructor throws exception, `captureInitSettings` will be null, if you don't it will be previous value. But generally no one writes code like this.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yup, I noticed that as I was writing an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *only* point in doing this would be if the `MediaCaptureInitializationSettings` constructor could throw an exception, and you wanted to make sure that in that case the variable didn't still have a reference to an "old" object. That's pretty rarely useful, in my experience. (If a method like this throws an exception, I'd try to avoid using the object it was initializing...)

I'd recommend doing all of this with an object initializer:

```
_captureInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    AudioDeviceId = "",
    VideoDeviceId = _deviceList.Count > 0 ? _deviceList[0].Id : "",
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.AudioAndVideo,
    PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview
};
```

This has two benefits:

- It's simpler code, IMO... much less repetition
- It only sets the variable's value if the whole object initializer completes. If setting one property fails, you don't end up with a reference to a half-initialized object.

Comment: Apart from the exception behavior which I noted already looking at the OP's code, I was about to comment that was written by some stupid. But later realized it was from msdn, Oh no!. Ummm, that doesn't make it a better code, it is still a stupid code.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes, unfortunately there are plenty of bad samples on MSDN :(

Comment: Yes Jon, there are even code snippets which even hurts you. Here is one [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360252/when-using-filestream-readasync-should-i-open-the-file-in-async-mode/27360773#27360773)

Answer (score 1):

I consider it good practice to set all fields of a newly constructed class to some well known default value.

Why?

First it is basic "code hygiene".

Second: while this makes not much sense in a small example which just shows a constructor, imagine a scenario where the fields of this class are modified at a later stage. If during this modifications something goes wrong, i.e. an Exception is thrown, it may leave your class in a bad state.

Comment: Fields are already initialized to default values - null, 0 etc. There's no need to do that explicitly. (It's not clear that this is during construction at all, given that it's in a method.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example we cannot tell if it serves a purpose or not.

What you are doing is setting the current instance of MediaCaptureInitializationSettings to NULL and then creating a new instance of MediaCaptureInitializationSettings.

The variable you set to NULL doesn't affect the new instance.

Comment: Follow the link if you want to see the whole example. It's just a fragment of it

Comment: You never set an *object* to null. You set a *variable* to null. It doesn't make any different to the object that the variable's old value referred to.

Comment: I don't see the fix - you're still saying "setting the current instance [...] to NULL".

Comment: @JonSkeet Im not sure what you mean?? _captureInitSettings is an instance of MediaCapture.... and hes setting it to NULL.